# SUMPRODUCT + INDIRECT reference, How to make it work if i'm adding rows?

Tags: microsoft-excel, macos, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a question/problem, I have an excel formula that looks something like this

`=(SUMPRODUCT(((INDIRECT("'"&G9&"'!"&$A$9)=$I$6)*(INDIRECT("'"&G9&"'!"&$B$9)))))/1.16`

It is the first time that I do a formula this complex and long lol, thing is, I got it to work, however, on the sheet that it is referencing there are some rare occasions where I need to add more rows, and I want them to also be taken into account.

Basically the file is a cash report for our stores, and it has 31 tab (for each day of the month) and even though it has some rows there are some good days when we sell more than expected, that's why we need to add more rows, right below the range in `(INDIRECT("'"&G9&"'!"&$B$9)`, how do I make it dynamic?

Here's everything the formula is referencing:

`(INDIRECT("'"&G9&"'!"&$A$9)=$I$6)*(INDIRECT("'"&G9&"'!"&$B$9)`

G9 = 1 (each tab is named after a number, for each day of the month)

$A$9 = A9:A20 (The range of the seller we want to find on the report)

$I$6 = A dropdown cell with the names of the sellers

$B$9 = D9:G20 (all the amounts we need to sum according to the payment method)

We want that, if for some reason we add another row, instead of taking into account A20 and G20 it takes into account A21 and G21

Everything is formatted as text on G9 A9 and B9 on the sheet where the formula is located

Here's a screenshot of the sales report
[Report where the formula is located](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vmzP.png)

And here's a screenshot of where the data is added (where we need to add rows below the 20th row)
[Cash Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ii67b.png)

I really can't find a way to make the Indirect formula take into account new rows added to an specific tab.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The core of your problem is `it has 31 tab (for each day of the month)`. Don't do that. Use one sheet for data entry only, then you won't have problems working with ALL of the data.

Comment: Is D21:F21 a merged cell or just formatted to look merged? In other words, what cell contains *Total sin in IVA*?

Comment: it is merged :P

Comment: Thing is that we need to be able to find the specific day of the month easily, that's why we made it on each tab, maybe there's an easier way for doing so on a single sheet, but we don't know yet. Also, it is made like that because at the end of the day they print it out. If I were to make it on a single sheet with formulas I don't know how I can get to the same filtering results

Answer (score 1):

Use the calculation on each sheet, same location on each sheet. Then you can use Indirect() to pull the result of the calculation from each sheet.

A better approach would be not to distribute the data across 31 sheets. That is bad data architecture. Enter all data on one sheet, use a column for the date. Then you can build any report with any kind of summary using pivot tables or formulas, for example totals per week, totals per weekday, etc. Much easier and much more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Put these in A9:B9.

```
="A9:"&ADDRESS(MATCH("Total sin in IVA", INDIRECT(TEXT(G9, "'0'!\D:\D")), 0)-1, 1, 4, 1)
="D9:"&ADDRESS(MATCH("Total sin in IVA", INDIRECT(TEXT(G9, "'0'!\D:\D")), 0)-1, 7, 4, 1)
```

The above formula assumes that 1!D21:F21 is a merged cell containing *Total sin in IVA*.